# Improving Performance Math Equations

Tags: performance, time

I'm taking a class called Computer Structures.  Currently, I have to do some performance improvement problems.  I'm banging my head against the wall, as I've been trying to figure the problems out for a few hours, and still have no idea how to approach it.  Our teacher gave us one single problem in class, that was an entirely different problem with a different setup and never taught us how to solve problems like this.  I'm not asking for anyone to do my homework, but to help guide me.  I'm feel as if I'm losing my mind currently.  The problem is a rather large, 3 part problem, and if I knew more about it, I'd know whether I'd need to include the other parts or not, but because I don't know, I'll just have to apologize for the length of the problem and post all 3.  I did the first two parts, but I have no clue if they are even correct.

3 processors:

```
P1: 2.0 GHz, 1.5 CPI
P2: 1.5 GHz, 1.0 CPI
P3: 3.0 GHz, 2.5 CPI
```

A) Which processor has the highest performance:

```
(My work)

Instruction Set = i, 1.5 GHz = 666.6 ps per cycle, 2 GHz = 500 ps per cycle, 3 GHz = 333.3 ps per cycle

P1 = i x 1.5 x 500   = i x 750
P2 = i x 1.0 x 666.6̅  = i x 666.6̅ (highest performance)
P3 = i x 2.5 x 333.3̅  = i x 833.3̅
```

B) Find the number of cycles and the number of instructions for each if all 3 run a program for 10 seconds:

```
(My work)

P1 = (2x10^9)   x 10 seconds = (2.0x10^10) cycles / 1.5 = (1.3̅ x 10^10) instructions
P2 = (1.5x10^9) x 10 seconds = (1.5x10^10) cycles / 1.0 = (1.5 x 10^10) instructions
P3 = (3x10^9)   x 10 seconds = (3.0x10^10) cycles / 2.5 = (1.2 x 10^10) instructions
```

C) **We are trying to reduce the time by 30% but this leads to an increase of 20% in CPI.  What clock rate should we have to get this time reduction?**

```
(My work)

20% increase in CPI = Old CPI x 1.2 | 30% decrease from 10 seconds is 7 seconds.
P1: CPI = 1.5 x 1.2 = 1.8 -> ((1.3̅  x 10^10) x 1.8) / 7 seconds = ~3.43 GHz
P2: CPI = 1.0 x 1.2 = 1.2 -> ((1.5 x 10^10) x 1.2) / 7 seconds = ~2.57 GHz
P3: CPI = 2.5 x 1.2 = 3   -> ((1.2 x 10^10) x 3.0) / 7 seconds = ~5.14 GHz
```

This is the part I'm having issues with.  I'm not sure if the past answers are correct either, but I only included them because I don't know if I needed them for the third part.

Any help / guidance would be much appreciated.  I've only come to SO after many failed attempts.

Comment: Your answers to part B are incorrect, use some dimensional analysis.  (And also note that the answer you gave was totally inconsistent with the answer to part A)

Comment: @BenVoigt - I'm a bit confused on how to fix part B.  I figured cycles would be total cycles in one second x total seconds.  For instance, 2 GHz would be 2x10^9 and that would be multiplied by 10 seconds, producing 20x10^9 cycles, or 2x10^10.

Comment: Are the issues in the instruction count?  Should I be dividing the total cycles by the CPI?  So 2x10^10 / 1.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase 20% in CPI -> p1: 1.8cpi, p2: 1.2cpi, p3: 3cpi

Reduce **time** by 30%, the only reference to time is in question B) which is 10 seconds. Reduce it by 30% makes it 7 seconds.

So, take number of instructions from your answer in B), multiply them by CPI then divide by 7 seconds. That should give you the clock rate.

Comment: Should I be dividing by CPI? or multiplying by CPI then dividing by 7?

Clock Rate = (Instruction Count x CPI) / CPU Time

Comment: @joe_04_04 sorry, multiply. fixed